# Novel in which a research team investigates a rip in the fabric of space

Tags: story-identification, novel, space

I read this sometime in the late 80s.

A science experiment causes a rip in the fabric of space. A being (person?) joins a research team that goes to investigate by creating a scion of themselves. They find that possibly a new life form has emerged within the rip. The action takes place in a space station.

Comment: So you're not sure if any of the characters were human? Also, was the first being you mentioned the only one who created a copy of themselves, or did the whole team do that?

Comment: Was about to suggest *Order of the Stick* until you mentioned the space station. :)

Comment: What's a _scion of themselves_? Do you mean a clone or other type of copy, or a descendant? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scion

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This may be Greg Egan's 2002 novel *[Schild's Ladder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schild%27s_Ladder)* (which is now just over two decades old) about a science experiment that creates a section of space growing in all directions at half the speed of light. The heroes create avatars of themselves that can survive inside to find out what's going on there.

> Twenty-thousand years in the future, Cass, a **humanoid** physicist from
> Earth, travels to an **orbital station** in the vicinity of the star
> Mimosa, and begins a series of **experiments** to test the extremities of
> the fictitious Sarumpaet rules – a set of fundamental equations in
> "Quantum Graph Theory", which holds that physical existence is a
> manifestation of complex constructions of mathematical graphs.
> However, the experiments unexpectedly create a **bubble of something
> more stable than ordinary vacuum**, dubbed "novo-vacuum", that expands
> outward at half the speed of light as ordinary vacuum collapses to
> this new state at the border, hinting at more general laws beyond the
> Sarumpaet rules.

Egan's own website describes the later part of the book like [this](https://www.gregegan.net/SCHILD/SCHILD.html):

> As a theoretical breakthrough leads to a sequence of experiments that
> begins to reveal the true richness of the world behind the border,
> tensions between the opposing factions grow. When a splinter group
> responds to these revelations with violent, unilateral action,
> Tchicaya and Mariama are forced into an uneasy alliance, and **travel
> together through the border**, balancing old and new loyalties against
> the fate of two incomparably different universes.

Comment: That's certainly sci-fi, with the time travel involved to have the OP having read it in the late 80s.

Comment: Yeah that's a problem - but people are sometimes wrong about when they've read a book.

Comment: Ha, I remember very little other than the germ if the plot!

Comment: I think this is the correct answer and I’m going to mark it as such. i’m honestly surprised that the book is this recent, my memory was of reading it earlier. Thanks very much!

Comment: i’m so thrilled to get this answer, I just stumbled across the site.

Comment: Come back with more questions!